# java.lang.RuntimeException : Could not open input channel pair

Tags: android, bluetooth, runtime-error, fatal-error

I'm testing my application with three phones (running andorid version : 4.1.2 - 4.0.4 - 2.3.6). They exchange data via Bluetooth without problems until this error appears in the logcat and the phone shutdowns completely and restarts. Before this error appears everything works perfectly.

Here is the logcat output on the phone that crashes (the one running version 4.1.2):

```
05-29 12:11:36.887: E/InputTransport(2947): channel '418655a8 Toast' ~ Could not create socket pair.  errno=24
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open input channel pair.  status=-24
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at android.view.InputChannel.nativeOpenInputChannelPair(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at android.view.InputChannel.openInputChannelPair(InputChannel.java:91)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2295)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at com.android.server.wm.Session.add(Session.java:139)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:70)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:111)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/JavaBinder(2947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947): Window Session Crash
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open input channel pair.  status=-24
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at android.view.InputChannel.nativeOpenInputChannelPair(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at android.view.InputChannel.openInputChannelPair(InputChannel.java:91)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2295)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at com.android.server.wm.Session.add(Session.java:139)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:70)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:111)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
05-29 12:11:36.897: E/WindowManager(2947):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.907: D/AndroidRuntime(8234): Shutting down VM
05-29 12:11:36.907: W/dalvikvm(8234): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abc300)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234): java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized.
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.<init>(InputEventReceiver.java:68)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:626)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:220)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:391)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:309)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-29 12:11:36.927: E/AndroidRuntime(8234):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 12:11:36.947: W/ActivityManager(2947):   Force finishing activity com.vittorio/.tabContainer.FloatyTab
05-29 12:11:36.967: E/IMemory(2947): binder=0x23b2708 transaction failed fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Unknown error: 2147483646)
05-29 12:11:36.967: E/IMemory(2947): cannot dup fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Bad file number)
05-29 12:11:36.967: E/IMemory(2947): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x23b2708), size=0, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
```

I don't know how this could be triggered by my application, there is not even one line inside this error output that points to one of my classes.

Also on my S3 with android v4.1.1 I got this error and the phone rebooted after 80 min of normal activity:

```
05-29 16:13:47.455: E/InputChannel-JNI(7490): Error 9 dup channel fd -2147483647.
05-29 16:13:47.455: D/AndroidRuntime(7490): Shutting down VM
05-29 16:13:47.455: W/dalvikvm(7490): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4101a2a0)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:135)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:523)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:663)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:220)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:431)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:348)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-29 16:13:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(7490):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And again my S3 resetted with the same error of my Samsung S plus (v 4.1.2) after correctly working for 3 hours, here is the log:

```
05-30 14:11:59.455: E/InputTransport(2262): channel '422b4910 Toast' ~ Could not create socket pair.  errno=24
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open input channel pair.  status=-24
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at android.view.InputChannel.nativeOpenInputChannelPair(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at android.view.InputChannel.openInputChannelPair(InputChannel.java:91)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2931)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at com.android.server.wm.Session.add(Session.java:139)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:70)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:111)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/JavaBinder(2262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262): Window Session Crash
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open input channel pair.  status=-24
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at android.view.InputChannel.nativeOpenInputChannelPair(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at android.view.InputChannel.openInputChannelPair(InputChannel.java:91)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2931)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at com.android.server.wm.Session.add(Session.java:139)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:70)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:111)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
05-30 14:11:59.465: E/WindowManager(2262):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.470: D/AndroidRuntime(13879): Shutting down VM
05-30 14:11:59.470: W/dalvikvm(13879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410c92a0)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879): java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized.
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.<init>(InputEventReceiver.java:68)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:4477)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:738)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:220)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:431)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:348)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-30 14:11:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(13879):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 14:11:59.515: E/IMemory(2262): cannot dup fd=1023, size=765952, err=0 (Too many open files)
05-30 14:11:59.515: E/IMemory(2262): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x5efc9c38), size=765952, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
05-30 14:11:59.515: A/libc(2262): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000075df (code=1), thread 4933 (Binder_9)
05-30 14:11:59.515: A/libc(2262): Unable to open connection to debuggerd: Too many open files
05-30 14:11:59.685: W/Sensors(24753): sensorservice died [0x40d75010]
```

Comment: any idea about this issue? please share

Comment: I reported an issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=108859

Answer (score 4):

this is a bug.
maybe you can check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32470 for some updates..

Comment: Actually this is not the same, in the link you provided there is a following error: "Error 24 dup" which is EMFILE 24/* Too many open files */. While in OP logcat you can see: "Error 9 dup channel", where 9 is "Bad file number". I am facing the same problem as OP but with no luck yet.

Comment: @marcin_j Any solution till now for this issue?