# What might be the reason for this exception? java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. Sometimes I get the following application crash. I dont know why. Can anyone help me with this?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized.
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.<init>(InputEventReceiver.java:70)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:5589)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:579)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2833)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Appretiate your help. :)

Comment: Actually I don't know where exactly this crash occurs. Which is why I did not post the code. The application just crashes randomly at any point of time after hours of testing.

Comment: I've got the same issue, I launched the beta testing of my application and noticed this crash report in Crashlytics. Device Samsung SM N910C, Android 5.1.1, rooted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a known bug, see here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=108859

Comment: thanks for the reference!Apparently related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811614/java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-open-input-channel-pair from the discussion?

Comment: OPPO device specific have this crash

Comment: Still have this problem 6 years later.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=108859 - doesn't have a fix yet.

Android Studio restart didn't help, but I managed to work around it with a device restart.